# trying to build a Response object for a Java RESTful service

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee

I am trying to build a Response object with a information I am getting back from a database.  The information I am getting back is in a Change object:

The `change.getDocument()` coming back is:

```
{"testSolution":false,"solutionId":333,"clientId":4018593,"firewall":false,"pod":"pod3.dmy3","networkPolicy":{"speed":"1","subnets":{"nat":{"vlan":3004,"cidr":["110.168.0.0/24"]},"private":{"vlan":3004,"cidr":["15.10.1.128/25"]}}}}
```

So I am creating a Response like this:

```
 return Response.status(422).location(location).entity(changeRequest).build();
```

In the unit test I do this:

```
    String responseJson = response.readEntity(String.class);
    System.out.println("The response is: " + responseJson);
```

For testing, but I get this result:

```
The response is: {"object_id" : 333,"object_type" : "class com.entities.Solution", "operation" : "", "revision" : 0, "remote_user" : "",   "remote_host" : "", "created" : "", "published" : "", "comment" : "HTTP Status Code 422", "error" : "HTTP Status Code 422, there is a pending change request for this Solution. Replying with pending ChangeRequest",  "document" : {} }
```

Everything is as expected, but the document node contains no information.  Am I building the Response object correctly?

Comment: Have you  error 400?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to return it in this way:

```
Response.status(Status.OK).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .entity(changeRequest).build();
```